# Can I program a TS87C51U2 with a UART? With which programmer can I program it?

Tags: uart

I have an [Atmel TS87C51U2 8bit microcontroller with dual UART.](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/587324/ATMELCorporation/TS87C51U2/1)

I want to program the IC with a serial to USB module (TTL) or with an Arduino.

Is it possible do this? Which program do I need?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please verify that this is [the datasheet](https://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/atmel/ts8051u2.pdf) of the part that you're talking about, and if so, _edit your question_ to include this link.

Comment: Not exactly, I will edit the post and send the data sheet is it for ATMEL company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look further on into the [Atmel TS87C51U2 datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/182327/ATMEL/TS87C51U2.html), at section 9.3 (below).

That makes it clear that the internal EPROM requires an external programmer, which must be capable of providing a 12.75 V programming voltage. The external programmer must put the MCU into a programming mode the manipulate the MCU pins to programme the EPROM then read it back to verify programming success.

The EPROM non-volatile technology is the predecessor of the convenient Flash EPROM. The latter is now used plentifully in MCUs and supports in-system programming and erasure at the normal MCU supply voltage.

In-system EPROM reprogramming requires the ability to overwrite existing data with all values of new data. That isn't possible with EPROM anyway, which requires exposure to ultra-violet light to erase it. That had to be shone through a window in the part package for 20-odd minutes.

[image]

Comment: It appears the memory is One-Time Programmable (OTP). There is no window for erasing so no need to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response and time, Can you introduce a programmer that can do that?

Comment: @Qteam, you're very welcome but finding a programmer is an Internet search job best done by yourself, as you know your budget, application and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If, indeed, that is the data sheet, then no -- it's an EPROM part, which means that during programming it won't be operating in a normal fashion.  You basically need an EPROM programmer.  Moreover, you need an EPROM eraser (and you need to have a part with a window) to blank out the chip in preparation of programming.

Comment: The part is one time programmable and can't be erased.

Comment: Doesn't the 7 in 87C mean that it's EPROM?  I was assuming it was the 83 part that was OTP.  But -- sure.  Either way, you can't just hook up a serial port to it and do the deed.